Use a different MavenRepository for Maven Openrewrite plugin
I am trying to write an openrewrite recipe that changes a maven dependency. The problem is I want to apply this recipe for a dependency that doesn't exist in the default maven repository (a.e. mavenCentral where Openrewrite in looking for it) and I get the following warning
Suppressed: org.openrewrite.maven.MavenDownloadingException: Unable to download POM. Tried repositories: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2: HTTP 404
Is there a way to set a different maven repository as the default one for openrewrite ?
I wrote unit tests and tried different approaches. I created my own recipe for changing a dependency but it still looks for the dependency in mavenCentral.

When OpenRewrite runs we pick up on how you've configured your Maven settings. Do you have a ~/.m2/settings.xml file defined? Or how are your defining your repositories to use?
Are you seeing this problem only in your unit tests, or also when running with the rewrite-maven-plugin? If the latter than you can run with exportDatatables enabled, as seen here:
https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/maven/upgradedependencyversion
That will then create a data table in a folder like this one:

That data table might then contain additional information on what was attempted, and sharing any such details might help get this resolved for you.
